# fork() child and parent processes

Tags: c, fork, parent

I am trying to create a program that uses fork() to create a new process. The sample output should look like so:

This is the child process. My pid is 733 and my parent's id is 772.
This is the parent process. My pid is 772 and my child's id is 773.

This is how I coded my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    printf("This is the child process. My pid is %d and my parent's id is %d.\n", getpid(), fork());

    return 0;
}
```

This results in the output:

This is the child process. My pid is 22163 and my parent's id is 0.
This is the child process. My pid is 22162 and my parent's id is 22163.

Why is it printing the statement twice and how can I get it to properly show the parent's id after the child id displays in the first sentence?

EDIT:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
int pid = fork();

if (pid == 0) {
    printf("This is the child process. My pid is %d and my parent's id is %d.\n", getpid(), getppid());
}
else {
    printf("This is the parent process. My pid is %d and my parent's id is %d.\n", getpid(), pid);
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also, `fork` does not return a parent process ID to the child. It returns 0 to the child and child's ID to the parent. That's how you know which is which.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Start by reading the [fork man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) as well as the [getppid](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getppid.html) / [getpid](http://linux.die.net/man/2/getpid) man pages.

From fork's

> On success, the PID of the child process is returned in the parent's
>   thread of execution, and a 0 is returned in the child's thread of
>   execution. On failure, a -1 will be returned in the parent's context,
>   no child process will be created, and errno will be set appropriately.

So this should be something down the lines of

```
if ((pid=fork())==0){
    printf("yada yada %u and yada yada %u",getpid(),getppid());
}
else{ /* avoids error checking*/
    printf("Dont yada yada me, im your parent with pid %u ", getpid());
}
```

As to your question:

> This is the child process. My pid is 22163 and my parent's id is 0.
>
> This is the child process. My pid is 22162 and my parent's id is
>   22163.

`fork()` executes before the `printf`. So when its done, you have two processes with the same instructions to execute. Therefore, printf will execute twice. The call to `fork()` will return `0` to the child process, and the `pid` of the child process to the parent process.

You get two running processes, each one  will execute this <strike>instruction</strike> statement:

```
printf ("... My pid is %d and my parent's id is %d",getpid(),0);
```

and

```
printf ("... My pid is %d and my parent's id is %d",getpid(),22163);
```

~

To wrap it up, the above line is the child, specifying its `pid`. The second line is the parent process, specifying its id (22162) and its child's (22163).

Comment: And it prints twice because... (from fork's man): After a new child process is created, both processes will execute the next instruction following the fork() system call. Therefore, we have to distinguish the parent from the child. This can be done by testing the returned value of fork()

Comment: Thanks so much, this was a GREAT breakdown. I edited my revised code above. It seems to work properly. Would you mind double checking to see that my logic is correct?

Comment: @raphnguyen Everyone should call `getppid()` to get their parent's process id. In your sample, the parent process will print its child process id instead.

Answer (score 2):

It is printing the statement twice because it is printing it for both the parent and the child.  The parent has a parent id of 0

Try something like this:

```
 pid_t  pid;
 pid = fork();
 if (pid == 0) 
    printf("This is the child process. My pid is %d and my parent's id is %d.\n", getpid(),getppid());
 else 
    printf("This is the parent process. My pid is %d and my parent's id is %d.\n", getpid(), getppid() );
```

Answer (score 2):

We control fork() process call by if, else statement. See my code below:

```
int main()
{
   int forkresult, parent_ID;

   forkresult=fork();
   if(forkresult !=0 )
   {
        printf(" I am the parent my ID is = %d" , getpid());
        printf(" and my child ID is = %d\n" , forkresult);
   }
   parent_ID = getpid();

   if(forkresult ==0)
      printf(" I am the  child ID is = %d",getpid());
   else
      printf(" and my parent ID is = %d", parent_ID);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is printing twice because you are calling printf twice, once in the execution of your program and once in the fork.  Try taking your fork() out of the printf call.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way for getting the correct output.... However, childs parent id maybe sometimes printed as 1 because parent process gets terminated and the root process with pid = 1 controls this orphan process.

```
 pid_t  pid;
 pid = fork();
 if (pid == 0) 
    printf("This is the child process. My pid is %d and my parent's id 
      is %d.\n", getpid(), getppid());
 else 
     printf("This is the parent process. My pid is %d and my parent's 
         id is %d.\n", getpid(), pid);
```